# reading a pdf file from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this example http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

The upload part is happening without any trouble. But I am facing a lot of problems in the download part of it. I want to create a link on which the user clicks and then he is able to download the appropriate pdf. But the page runs and the anchor tag is visible. But when i click on it .htm file is getting downloaded
below is my download.php

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Download File From MySQL</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM upload";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
echo "Database is empty <br>";
}
else
{
while(list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<?php echo "<a href='download.php?id='".$id.";>Download</a> <br>";

}
}
include 'closedb.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
// if id is set then get the file with the id from database

include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$id    = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT name, type, size, content " .
         "FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $content;

include 'closedb.php';
exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the top of the page you start the html output regardless whether the user wants to see the files to be downloaded, or wants to download the file itself. In that moment the file to be downloaded bacomes an html page.

Your code should start with a check if the id parameter is set. If not, then you start generating the html page. If yes, then you read the file from the db, set the headers and send the contents back.

Or just use a different php page for displaying the list of files and downloading one of the files.

Comment: I am fairly new to this. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: Pls be specific: what do you need help with! You already have the if checking for the id parameter to be set. If you are not great with php just yet, then consider my suggestion of separating the list and the download functions into 2 php files.