# display BLOB pdf directly on webpage as download link

Tags: mysql, pdf

I have a table in MySQL database. It consists of many columns. The last column is BLOB column and it is storing pdf files. I want to call particular columns of the table. The BLOB column is the last one. I want the `<td>` elements to say Download and on click of the anchor tag I want the pdf to get downloaded. Somebody please help. The values of the Copy Column is going to be pdf files.

```html
$result=  mysql_query("SELECT Name, Type, No, Copy from table1 Join table2 where username='{$_SESSION['username']}' AND table1.UserID=table2.UserID") or die(mysql_error());
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
 echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
 echo "<th>Name</th>";
 echo "<th>Type</th>";
 echo "<th>Number</th>";
 echo "<th>Copy</th>";
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['Name']."</td><td>".$row['Type']."</td><td>".$row['No']."</td><td>"."<a href=''>Download</td></tr>";
 }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to create a separate PHP file that does nothing but fetch the blob and output it. From the code above, you then link to that PHP file - that's your download link

Comment: ... like you already have in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354477/reading-a-pdf-file-from-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I save my files in a folder and just adding the path into a column in my database and to download I use the following PHP code.

I call it downloadPop_Up.php:

```
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
//header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($data) . "\"");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($data) . "\"");
readfile($data);
?>
```

Comment: This is going to fail if the data is more than a couple of kilobytes large. Many clients can't handle URLs that are larger than 8 kilobytes or so.

Comment: Really ? How I can fix it ? I am using it in my web apps and I hope it didn't make troubles for my clients

Comment: Ah, no, I misread the code - you're not transmitting vast amounts of code, but you're passing a file path that anyone can modify, that's even *more* dangerous. Someone could change the path to a PHP file, for example, and download your app's source code and config settings. I can't tell you how to fix it because it's unclear where the `$data` file comes from and how it is generated

Comment: `$data` is the link where a file is (I.E. `uploads/picture1.jpg`) Please, is their any stronger code than this ? I need to make changes as fast as possible

Comment: You could change the script to make sure only files from `uploads/` are allowed.

Comment: like this : `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . uploads\basename($data) . "\"");`

Comment: No, it's the `readfile()` that's the problem. Something like `readfile("/path/to/your/uploads/".basename($data));` should make it impossible to traverse outside of the uploads directory.

Comment: okay, but if they use this to just download all what I have in the upload folder ?

Comment: Cz in this folder, every user can see his own uploads

Comment: Then you need to put the files in a different folder I suppose.

Comment: Isn't their any other script ?